# yii editable url is adding google analytic before main url

Tags: yii, x-editable

I am using below code to display editable field in my view page. Display looks good. However, when I click on save, its not going to general controller index action. If I see network, request url has google analytic domain before the domain I have set. Any reason to this?

```
$this->widget('editable.Editable', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'user_name',
    'encode' => false,
    'text' => 'John',
    'url' => 'general/index',
    'title' => 'Enter Name',
    'placement' => 'right'
));
```

Also I am getting js error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editableSuccess' of undefined
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related but shouldn't it be `$this->createUrl("general/index")` and not `'$this->createUrl("general/index")'`. Without the `''`, otherwise you are passing that string literal to the widget.

Comment: @RaulSauco The actual value of url is 'general/index'. But it's still adding google analytic domain in front

Comment: It could be that is your server doing that and not Yii, are you serving on `localhost`?

Comment: @RaulSauco No, also there is js error from editable as I have mentioned above